# How to dynamically create multiple jQuery sliders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on a WordPress site that turns a custom post type into a slider on a page. I am using [Sequence.js](http://www.sequencejs.com/) for my slider and I can manually create multiple sliders no problem with the following:

```
//sequence slider options to be used by slider1
var options0 = {
    sartingFrameID: 1,
    cycle: true,
    autoPlay: false,
    nextButton: '.next0',
    prevButton: '.prev0',
    fallback: {
        theme: "fade",
        speed: 100
    }
}

//slider1
var sequence0 = $(".slideContainer0").sequence(options0).data("sequence");

//sequence slider options to be used by slider2
var options1 = {
    sartingFrameID: 1,
    cycle: true,
    autoPlay: false,
    nextButton: '.next1',
    prevButton: '.prev1',
    fallback: {
        theme: "fade",
        speed: 100
    }
}

//slider2
var sequence1 = $(".slideContainer1").sequence(options1).data("sequence");
```

How can I streamline this? And also make it dynamic so a slider is created for each post that is made? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**edited - added working answer**

I used the answer from Cymen below for the first part by turning the options output into a function and simply calling the function with a counter for each sequence instance. Then used the second part of his answer to initialize each sequence slider and it works a treat.

This is what I have working now:

```
function options(number) {
    return {
        startingFrameID: 1,
        cycle: true,
        autoPlay: false,
        nextButton: '.next' + number,
        prevButton: '.prev' + number,
        fallback: {
            theme: "fade",
            speed: 100
        }
    };
}

var count = 0;
$('.slideContainer').each(function() {
    var sequence = $(this); 
    sequence.sequence(options(count)).data('sequence');
    count++;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used sequence but from your post I am guessing you want to be able to recreate the options object with an increment of the number. So you could do something like this:

```
function options(number) {
  return {
   startingFrameID: 1,
    cycle: true,
    autoPlay: false,
    nextButton: '.next' + number,
    prevButton: '.prev' + number,
    fallback: {
        theme: "fade",
        speed: 100
    }
  };
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
$(target).sequence(options(0)).data("sequence");
```

Or in your specific example:

```
//slider1
var sequence0 = $(".slideContainer0").sequence(options(0)).data("sequence");

//slider2
var sequence1 = $(".slideContainer1").sequence(options(1)).data("sequence")
```

And to do what you are talking about how about giving all the sequences the same class like say `custom-sequence` and then do something like this:

```
var count = 0;
$('.custom-sequence').each(function() {
  var sequence = $(this);
  sequence.sequence(options(count)).data('sequence');
  count++;
});
```

That may or may not work -- it isn't quite clear to me what the `.data('sequence')` is doing.

Comment: The first part of your answer doesn't work. Multiple sliders get setup, but the options aren't separated. The Prev & Next buttons don't function properly as both sliders advance when pressing Next on either one. Furthermore, the sliders show the same behaviour as if they are being created with the same options.

Comment: Are you passing in the correct number to match `'.next' + number`? I'm assuming the HTML with the next and prev classes is created elsewhere. An example of it working on jsbin.com (or a similar site) would make it possible to help you figure it out much quicker.

Comment: Yes, the .next/.prev are created with a matching iterating number. I am going to try with another slider plugin and see how that goes as the more I look at this, the more it looks like Sequence JS is being the culprit.

Comment: I have edited the original post explaining why I gave you credit for the answer, and the last part I need to figure out. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Disregard that last comment, I used the second part of your answer to initialize each sequence slider and it works great now. Thanks!