# Multiple Sliders With Sequence.js and pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, slider, sequence

I have several sliders that each have a different number of slides. Each slider has no next/previous buttons but is instead controlled by pagination. Whenever a slider's pagination is clicked every slider's image advances to the corresponding pagination. So if the 2nd pagination button is clicked every slider goes to the 2nd image instead of just the current slider. I tried the following solution: http://bit.ly/1b1bvsC but this is only relevant for the next/previous buttons and doesn't work with pagination.

Here's my current js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var options = {
    nextButton: false,
    prevButton: false,
    pagination: true,
    animateStartingFrameIn: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    autoPlayDelay: 3000,
    preloader: true,
    startingFrameID: 1,
    preloadTheseFrames: [1],
}

var options2 = {
    nextButton: false,
    prevButton: false,
    pagination: true,
    animateStartingFrameIn: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    autoPlayDelay: 3000,
    preloader: true,
    startingFrameID: 2,
    preloadTheseFrames: [1],
}

var sequence = $("#essence-sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");
var sequence2 = $("#macropro-sequence").sequence(options2).data("sequence");

});
```

And here's a picture in case there's any confusion as to what I'm talking about:
[image: pagination slider]

So when the small circles at the bottom are clicked the big red image above will slide over to the corresponding "product image" without affecting any other sliders on the page. (Sorry for the nasty redness but I have to keep this on the DL for now)

Comment: Bueller? Bueller? Anyone?

Comment: So many views, so little help... :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and the solution found in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864930/how-to-dynamically-create-multiple-jquery-sliders) that you reference also works for pagination, not just next/previous buttons. You can give each set of pagination a different class and then input that class into the javascript.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var options = {
    nextButton: false,
    prevButton: false,
    pagination: '.pagination1', //name first pagination here
    animateStartingFrameIn: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    autoPlayDelay: 3000,
    preloader: true,
    startingFrameID: 1,
    preloadTheseFrames: [1],
}

var options2 = {
    nextButton: false,
    prevButton: false,
    pagination: '.pagination2', //name second pagination here
    animateStartingFrameIn: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    autoPlayDelay: 3000,
    preloader: true,
    startingFrameID: 2,
    preloadTheseFrames: [1],
}

var sequence = $("#essence-sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");
var sequence2 = $("#macropro-sequence").sequence(options2).data("sequence");

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Kevin. Unfortunately We've moved away from using Sequence.js as this project was urgent. Maybe I'll be able to implement your suggestion for a future project...

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still relevant...
From the docs:

> Multiples of the same user interface type can be used in each instance of Sequence.js (except for preloader which currently only allows one per instance), if you wish to have a next button in each step for example.
>
> When using multiple instances of Sequence.js, note that user interface
>   elements by default will control all Sequence.js instances. A next
>   button for example will control every instance of Sequence.js on the
>   page. Should you wish to have an UI element only control one instance
>   of Sequence.js, please use a rel attribute on the UI element, with a
>   value the same as the id for the Sequence.js instance you want the UI
>   element to control. For example:

```
<div rel="sequence1" class="seq-next">Next →</div>

<div id="sequence1">
  <!-- additional code removed for brevity -->
</div>

<div id="sequence2">
  <!-- additional code removed for brevity -->
</div>
```

> In the above code example, we have two instances of Sequence.js on the
>   page. With an attribute of rel="sequence1" applied to a next button,
>   only  will go to its next slide when the next
>   button is clicked. Likewise, should we change the attribute to
>   rel="sequence2", the second Sequence.js instance 
>   will navigate to its next slide. If the rel attribute is removed
>   entirely, both instances will go to the next slide. This applies to
>   all UI elements regardless of their position on the page — they can be
>   within or outside of Sequence.js elements.

All you need to do is add a *rel* attribute that matches the *id* of the sequence element.